# Find values of constants in equation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, linear-regression

I have equation `F(f)=a*f^3+b*f+c`. I have known vectors of the data, `p`, independent variable, 'f'. I need to find values of `a`, `b`, `c`.
What I tried:

```
function [ val ] = myfunc(par_fit,f,p)
    % This gives me a,b,c
    % p= af^3 +bf +c
    val = norm(p - (par_fit(1)*(f.^3))+ (par_fit(2)*f) + (par_fit(3)));
end
my_par = fminsearch(@(par_fit) myfunc(par_fit,f,p),rand(1,3));
```

This gives me `my_par = [1.9808 -2.2170 -24.8039]`, or `a=1.9808`, `b=-2.2170`, and `c=-24.8039`, but I require that `b` should be larger than 5, and `c` should be larger than zero.

Comment: `c` is not zero, it's -24.8039. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry I edited it, c cannot be less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Try `val = norm(p - par_fit(1) * f.^3 - par_fit(2) * f - par_fit(3));` as you are looking zero for `p - a * f^3 - b * f - c`

Comment: Thanks Cherry that gave me the mod of my previous my_par. However expected value of constants were. `2.45 6.57 14` Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be because your objective function is incorrect:

```
val = norm(p - (par_fit(1)*(f.^3))+ (par_fit(2)*f) + (par_fit(3)));
```

should probably be:

```
val = norm(p-(par_fit(1)*f.^3+par_fit(2)*f+par_fit(3)));
```

But you can constrain the values of variables when you do minimisation by using `fmincon` rather than `fminsearch`. By setting the `lb` input to `[-Inf -Inf 0]`, the first two coefficients are allowed to be any real number, but the third coefficient must be greater than or equal to zero. For example: (I've also shown how to solve the problem (without the non-negativity constraint) using a matrix method)

```
% Sample data
f=(0:.1:1).';
p=2*f.^3+3*f+1+randn(size(f))

% Create Van der Monde matrix
M=[f.^3 f f.^0];
C=M\p; % Solve the matrix problem in a least squares sense if size(f)>size(F)

my_par=fmincon(@(c) norm(p-(c(1)*f.^3+c(2)*f+c(3))),rand(1,3),[],[],[],[],[-Inf 5 0],[])
C.'

plot(f,p,'o',f,M*C,f,my_par(1)*f.^3+my_par(2)*f+my_par(3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation David. In this case I want b to be greater than five, so what should I change